# Bad moderators behavior - Account deleted without any reason

Tags: support, moderation, serial-voting, deleted-accounts, sock-puppets

I was deleted from Italian SE, my username was DaniChi, now I see “user5372".
I opened yet a ticket on May, 1st and my daughter (Marybnq) opened one too but for now, we had no response.
My daughter’s account was suspended, mine deleted because (I know this because she had a message, they said nothing to me), they think it was a duplicated account.

> **My daughter suddenly wrote that we are mother and daughter, but they ignored it.**

This is a shame, they deleted me, I think it was because I was too much "active" on the site.
**In fact, the same day they deleted me, I received an email by StackOverflow: “Top new Italian Language Stack Exchange users for the month of 4/1/2019!”.**
I joined the community a few time ago (around 11 April on this year), my daughter told me of that, I was registered only on StackOverflow, because I started studying Swift and SpriteKit about one and half year ago, but unfortunately, for now, I'm not as good as I would like to be, so there, I would need a lot of help and is difficult for me to ask, I still feel too inexperienced and now I can’t help anybody, I only need help, while in the Italian SE, I loved so much to answer to questions, because I’m great in Italian and in explaining things I know in a clear and concise manner.
But there is a strange atmosphere on the site, there, people are not happy to read an answer if you are not “one of them”.
I was kind and professional and received sarcastic comments or very fussy requests on the sources of my answers.
But I didn't care, I wanted to go ahead and do what I like.
But they didn't want to let me do it, so, for no credible reason, they banned me.

> **The most ridiculous part is they didn't even upvote me, some of my answers have 0 votes.**

Pay attention: **we are talking about a site where there are less than two questions a day**, despite having 4,911 users and 2,922 visitors/days, it seems deserted, so, if you visit it on daily basis, **the first Q&A you read are the ones to which the last answer was given**, I suppose then, if you read it and approve the content, that it is normal to vote up or down, relative or not.

Therefore we are not talking about random votes on bad content, and if someone who wrote the opposite on this page had taken the effort to check, he/she would have written different things.

In fact, I was born and live in Italy, Italian is my mother tongue, and although I have studied Italian in-depth, having done a scholastic course dedicated to classical studies, before giving "technical" answers, I carefully checked the grammatical rules also on my books, in order to provide all possible information to any non-Italian site visitors who check the site to learn Italian, trying to be as clear and schematic as possible and I am convinced that anyone who checks them (understanding the content) will realize the quality of the job done.

**I never gave "random" answers without knowing what I was talking about**, despite to what someone did here.

> I wanted to add that I have only one account and it's the same for all the StackExchange sites I joined.

They accused me of falsifying accounts, but if you check, you can find that I browsed the **unanswered questions**, and from 11 April to 1 May (the day they deleted me) I answered to these questions:

> [Question1](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10135/preposizioni-davanti-a-nomi-di-prodotti-come-whatsapp-facebook-instagram)
>   asked Dec 18 '18 at 21:30
>   answered Apr 11 at 12:17 user5372 (me)
>
> [Question2](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/cardinal-numbers-separation-of-words-with-a-space-beyond-100-000)
>   asked Oct 13 '17 at 16:35
>   answered Apr 12 at 9:42 user5372 (me)
>
> [Question3](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10365/avrei-dovuto-ricordarmi-che-vs-mi-sarei-dovuto-ricordare-che)
>   asked Mar 23 at 18:01
>   answered Apr 12 at 16:46 user5372 (me)
>
> [Question4](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10182/perch%C3%A9-si-dice-tutti-e-due-e-non-tutti-due)
>   asked on Jan 12 at 11:27
>   answered Apr 12 at 15:57 user5372 (me)
>
> [Question5](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10424/esiste-un-modo-per-sapere-quando-usare-le-doppie)
>   asked Apr 15 at 21:17
>   answered Apr 16 at 12:22 user5372 (me)
>
> [Question6](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10430/significato-di-oggi-sar%C3%B2-la-tempesta)
>   asked Apr 16 at 19:59
>   answered Apr 17 at 8:13 user5372 (me)
>
> [Question7](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10435/rules-for-feminine-forms-of-titles-e-g-professoressa-vs-signora)
>   asked Apr 18 at 2:31
>   answered Apr 18 at 5:41 user5372 (me)
>
> [Question8](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9423/what-language-was-spoken-in-13th-century-naples)
>   asked May 13 '18 at 20:54
>   answered Apr 19 at 0:36 user5372 (me)
>
> [Question9](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/how-different-was-dantes-spoken-dialect-from-the-language-of-the-divina-commedi)
>   asked May 13 '18 at 20:35
>   answered Apr 18 at 7:12 user5372 (me)
>
> [Question10](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9977/sulla-correttezza-di-molto-migliore)
>   asked Oct 22 '18 at 11:19
>   answered Apr 29 at 16:48 user5372 (me)
>
> [Question11](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10466/casual-versus-formal-jacket)
>   asked Apr 30 at 12:33
>   answered Apr 30 at 14:19 user5372
>
> [Question12](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9915/salire-scendere-con-quali-preposizioni)
>   asked Sep 28 '18 at 12:55
>   answered 2 days ago user5372 (one of my last answer on 1st May 19)
>
> [Question13](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10248/when-can-we-use-sparare-as-transitive-verb)
>   asked Feb 10 at 23:39
>   answered 2 days ago user5372 (one of my last answer on 1st May 19)

I think that’s all, I can’t find other answers.
Nobody answered to our tickets, for now, not to mine, nor my daughter’s.
Does somebody know how it works?
Is it normal to be treated this way (I meant: within the Italian SE site)?
I hope somebody can help.

**EDIT:**
I don't think my question is off topic for this site: it concerns the behavior of some members of one of the site, but it is something that can happen in all the sites of StackExchange and reading the answers that I have received, it is immediately clear that it has just happened also here:

1. many people write without making sure that they have checked the content, the point of the question and the totality of the facts (I'm sure this happens everywhere);
2. I cannot write on the Italian site meta, because I have been deleted, I will not create a new account in order to express my opinion, I would do exactly what I have been wrongly accused of.
3. I noticed that not all sites are moderated with care, I don't want to add details because I don't like to attack one or two specific people publicly, but this is just the problem why many small sites are almost "dead".

Comment: You might have a case if you were not warned, and if you and your daughter do have two separate accounts. I suppose there must be a couple of users who are married to each other or have siblings that visit the same website. I don't see why a spouse or a sibling should *never* cast a vote on an answer or question posted by their partner or sibling. It would be like expecting Don Junior Trump not to vote for his father or Michelle Obama not to support her husband. But you're definitely hiding something, maybe there is a third account, now-deleted, that you have conveniently forgot to mention.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's not that they should *never* cast a vote for each other; just that they're much more likely to be accused of voting fraud if it forms a pattern (voting statistics are clearly visible to mods). To be on the safe side, it's just to best to avoid that altogether.

Comment: I'll be cleaning up - the comments on this post, as well as answers. Considering you've contacted support, at least on the short term, the most constructive thing to do is just to wait a little. The CMs and other such folks can see stuff even "us" regular mods can't and in situations like this we often get feedback, both generally and more specifically. I know its a hot/emotional topic - so I'll try to leave the ones that're more useful, and helps OP and others figure out what went "wrong"

Comment: @JourneymanGeek ok, thanks.

Answer (score 22):

Based on the comment trail, your account was deleted because it was violating the rules surrounding voting, and your daughter's account was suspended because it was seen as the base account for sockpuppeting.

Let's go over this:  Vote on the content, and the content *alone*.  Not who posts it.  Not because you think it deserved an upvote.  Not because you think it didn't deserve a downvote.  You, and you alone, are responsible for your behaviour.

Accounts don't get deleted for no reason.  The justifications you're using for using your votes the way you did is without merit.  The excuses don't help you, only further solidify that the moderator's actions were correct.  How other people vote is not your concern, especially as there is zero proof one way or the other for how others voted.

There is a mod message that came with the suspension.  Read it.  That tells you why one account was suspended, and what not to do going forward.

Comment: It seems you didn’t understand that I voted JUST a few which I liked, as I vote everything I find interesting. I didn’t voted them because they were my moms

Comment: @Marybnq If you did that, the votes would be reversed the next day, and I suspect the pattern would be investigated.  If it showed a connection between us, I would likely be suspended, too.  If you persisted in upvoting me in an attempt to get me suspended, it would backfire and you would be suspended.

Comment: We could be friends from different countries. I’m not stupid I’m not doing that. No need to be say that

Comment: @Marybnq I repeat: Vote on the content, and the content *alone*.  The pattern you exhibited warranted suspension, and based on the account deletion, there's more to this story than you're telling.  Either way, I've said my piece.  It is up to you to accept it, or not.  I will not engage further.

Comment: @DaniChi: The basic point is this: yes, you can vote freely. However, if all or just most of the questions or answers you're looking at are from your daughter/parent, so all or most of your votes go towards your relation, *that* is a problem. If the two of you encounter each other incidentally a few times, that's fine. But if you're encountering each other *often enough* that the majority of your votes are for the other, that's not fine.

Comment: For context, moderators can’t see individual votes. They can only see ***patterns***. So, if your account was suspended and/or deleted, that means the moderators saw clear evidence of a targeted voting pattern. Regardless of why it might have happened, that behavior is a problem. You’re arguing that the site is small and relatively inactive, but that makes targeted voting patterns ***an even bigger problem***, because those targeted votes are more likely to skew the score of posts and the reputation of users.

Comment: What usually happens is that someone notices odd voting patterns, flags for mods, mods look at the accounts involved and see what % of the accounts votes are shared among each other. If it's high, accounts get suspended and deleted, depending on how obvious things are. And there are TONS of deleted accounts due to voting irregularities. Source: former mod.

Comment: @DaniChi you're confusing "repeated votes between some users" with "any votes between two users == insta-ban". That is not the case. As has already been outlined several times - the mods take action based on an apparent abusive pattern, in which most likely all or the majority of votes are focused between some specific users. if you go and downvote several of someone's posts, that's also considered abusive, but it isn't abusive if you happen to have downvoted a few of their posts throughout time - there's nothing abusive about that. If mods have suspended you, there's likely an abusive pattern

Comment: @Won't most of my answers have ZERO votes: there is not a problem of voting irregularities and Blue, when I wrote "we will see many deleted accounts", I mean that, if it is forbidden to vote for each other, the 5-10 accounts that feel themselves the "owners" of the site, who apply, give answers, and vote among themselves, will probably be the most penalized by this affair.

Comment: @DaniChi What do you mean by "most of my answers have ZERO votes"? Most of your answers you linked to in your question are upvoted.

Comment: @ModusTollens 4, 10, 12, 13 had zero votes, in a site where there are one or two answers a day. 8 and 9 had 1 vote... But that's not the problem I wanted to solve.

Comment: If it's worth mentioning, the quality of the answers by DaniChi is quite high. If her answers continue to carry a positive score it suggests that they were upvoted by the community and not by sockpuppets.  I think there must be some sort of deception but being the holder of two accounts or having a friend  or family member who likes your content and *occasionally* upvotes it,  is not the "crime",  it's upvoting one's own content that is being penalised.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks a lot

Comment: @Mari-LouA Based on the [reputation hit](https://italian.stackexchange.com/users/5327/marybnq?tab=reputation) her daughter took at the start of the suspension, this wasn't a one way street.  There is *far* more to this story than what we're being told.

Comment: @fbueckert  In an earlier  comment, I suggested that we didn't know the full story and we don't. There could be a 3rd account... Unfortunately, the comment  got deleted.